# can you copy files off of an iPhone in DFU mode to your computer without booting into IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to copy files from an iPhone in DFU mode to PC via USB cable, but have not been successful in finding a way to do that. It needs to be done without booting into IOS, so does anyone know if this is something that is achievable? If it is, then how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score -3):

I know it's not impossible. Theoretically you can do this with a jailbreak, but it's very difficult.